# No Market on Honeycomb for NOOKcolor

Tags: google-play-store, 3.0-honeycomb, nook-color

I put Honeycomb on my NOOKcolor and the app market is not on it. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [nook devs site](http://nookdevs.com/Honeycomb_Google_Apps_and_Market) provides links and goes over downloading Google apps to your Nook color running honeycomb. [This](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Latest_Version)site lists the available Google app downloads from Cyanogenmod, explaining that they cannot come pre-installed due to licensing restrictions. The links at the very bottom of the page (and the first link) should help you find the appropriate applications.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes custom ROMs come without the Google apps (Gmail, Market, Maps, etc.) pre-loaded, in those cases it's a separate package that you need to flash over the ROM.  You should check with the ROM developer where you should get the gapps from.